# copy MAP container to the end of X

Tags: c++11

Suppose that `m` has type `map<int, string>`, and we encounter a call to

`copy(m.begin(), m.end(), back_inserter(x))`.

What can we say about the type of x?

Please throw me an example if `copy(m.begin(), m.end(), back_inserter(x))` would be leagal. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What can we say about the type of x?

We can say that:

- `m.value_type` is `pair<const int, string>`, so the same is *probably* true of `x.value_type` (not strictly required, but conventional in STL).
- `x.push_back(value_type)` must be valid, for `back_inserter(x)` to work.

That is, the only requirement on `x` is that it supports the following:

```
x.push_back(pair<const int, string>());
```

It does not matter what this function actually does, but it must have this name and support this argument type.

Comment: `m`'s value type is `pair<const int, string>`.

Comment: Thanks, guys it's helpful. Got my example below for the records

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, everyone! Here is my example

```
map<int, string> m;         // 'm' is associative container with type map<int, string> 

m[1] = "Serge";
m[2] = "Iulia";

// 'back_inserter(x))' can be used for the container, so 'x' is a vector of pair
vector < pair<int, string> > x;

copy(m.begin(), m.end(), back_inserter(x));

// display vector of pair 'x'
cout << "vector <pair<int, string> > x" << endl;
for (vector<pair<int, string> >::const_iterator iter = x.begin(); iter != x.end(); ++iter) {
    cout << iter->first << " " << iter->second <<  endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

x must be a container type. `back_inserter` returns an iterator which is used to add elements to the end of the container passed as the parameter. See [std::back_inserter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter).

`back_inserter` is not legal for `std::map`. The container type given as the parameter must support `push_back` which `std::map` does not. To see for yourself: http://ideone.com/b2t2iN

Comment: I don't think the question suggested that x should be an std::map